# how to set background to color you have chosen

Tags: javascript, arrays, while-loop, onload

***Functionality:***

User to play a game whereby system will randomly select a color from a list in an array. When user selects the correct color, the background will display the correct color and a congratulatory msg will be displayed

***What has been done:***

Have set the while loop to do a continuous check on the condition and verification check is done within check_guess() method. have set `myBody=document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
                myBody.style.background = guess_input;` to display the correct color picked by the system.

***Issue:***

I am unable to display the correct color chosen by the system. It keeps displaying the first condition alert msg : "Sorry, i don't recognise your color. Please try again".

Secondly, I keep getting a prompt of "Sorry, i don't recognise your color. Please try again", even if I set the correct the color or any of the colors within the array

What have I done wrong and why is it not displaying the color that the system has chosen

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Color Guessing Game</title>
</head>

<body onload="do_game()">
  <script>
    var color = ["blue", "cyan", "gray", "green", "magenta", "orange", "red", "white", "yellow"];
    var guess_input_text, guess_input, finished = false,
      target, guesses = 0;

    function do_game() {

      var rnd = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9) + 0);
      target = color[rnd];
      alert(target);

      while (!finished) {
        guess_input_text = prompt("I am thinking of these colors:" +
          "\n\n blue, cyan, gray, green, magenta, orange, red, white, yellow" + "\n\n what color am I thinking of?");
        guess_input = parseInt(guess_input_text);
        guesses += 1;
        finished = check_guess();
      }
    }

    function check_guess(){
            
            if (guess_input_text != color){
                alert("Sorry, i don't recognise your color"+"\n Please try again");
                return false;
            } else if(guess_input_text == color){
                if(guess_input> target){
                    alert("Sorry, your guess is not correct!" +"\n Hint: Your color is alphabatically higher than mine" + "\n Please try again");
                    return false;
                }else if(guess_input< target){
                    alert("Sorry, your guess is not correct!" +"\n Hint: Your color is alphabatically lower than mine" + "\n Please try again");
                    return false;
                }
            }else{
                 alert ("Congratulations! You have guessed the color!"+"\nIt took you"+ guesses+" guesses to finish the game!" + "\n You can see the color in the background");
                document.body.style.backgroundColor = guess_input;
                return true;
            }
        }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're doing this wrong:

```
myBody.style.background = guess_input;
```

I think that you've forgotten to put this:

```
myBody.style.backgroundColor = guess_input;
```

Oh, and when you say:

```
if (guess_input != color) {
        alert("Sorry, i don't recognise your color" + "\n Please try again");
        return false;
      }
```

You're comparing a integer with an array. You have to compare the integer with the position of the array (not with the data in that position)

Comment: Does it mean that i should be using "guess_input_text" instead of "guess_input"?

Comment: yep, unless you want to write a number which indicates the position that you want.

Comment: I have tried the suggestion, however, the check is still looping even if I have set the color right

Comment: Could you edit your code in this page? I'd like to see how have you put the new code.

Comment: done edit.. what if I were to input the following line :`if (color.indexOf(guess_input) < 0)` instead of `if (guess_input_text != color)`, it still has the same poutcome

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the line `if (guess_input != color) {` will fail as `color` is an array. To check whether `guess_input` is in your `color` array, I would suggest using

```
if (color.indexOf(guess_input) < 0) {
```

The `array_variable.indexOf(value_to_check_for)` method will return the index that `value_to_check_for` is found at in `array_variable`, or -1 if it was not found at all. See [Array#indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) for more details and examples of usage.

Another problem with this is that you're trying to parse the string input into an integer, which you do not need you can change

```
guess_input_text = prompt("I am thinking of these colors:" +
          "\n\n blue, cyan, gray, green, magenta, orange, red, white, yellow" + "\n\n what color am I thinking of?");
        guess_input = parseInt(guess_input_text);
```

can be changed to:

```
guess_input = prompt("I am thinking of these colors:" +
          "\n\n blue, cyan, gray, green, magenta, orange, red, white, yellow" + "\n\n what color am I thinking of?");
```

Secondly, you might want to replace 
`myBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
 myBody.style.background = guess_input;`
with 
`document.body.style.backgroundColor = guess_input;` as using `getElementsByTagName` isn't necessary here.

The finished article would then look like:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Color Guessing Game</title>
</head>

<body onload="do_game()">
  <script>
    var color = ["blue", "cyan", "gray", "green", "magenta", "orange", "red", "white", "yellow"];
    var guess_input_text, guess_input, finished = false,
      target, guesses = 0;

    function do_game() {

      var rnd = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9) + 0);
      target = color[rnd];
      alert(target);

      while (!finished) {
        guess_input = prompt("I am thinking of these colors:" +
          "\n\n blue, cyan, gray, green, magenta, orange, red, white, yellow" + "\n\n what color am I thinking of?");
        guesses += 1;
        finished = check_guess();
      }
    }

    function check_guess() {
      if (color.indexOf(guess_input) < 0) {
        alert("Sorry, i don't recognise your color" + "\n Please try again");
        return false;
      }
      if (guess_input > target) {
        alert("Sorry, your guess is not correct!" + "\n Hint: Your color is alphabatically higher than mine" + "\n Please try again");
        return false;
      }
      if (guess_input < target) {
        alert("Sorry, your guess is not correct!" + "\n Hint: Your color is alphabatically lower than mine" + "\n Please try again");
        return false;
      }
      alert("Congratulations! You have guessed the color!" + "\nIt took you" + guesses + " guesses to finish the game!" + "\n You can see the color in the background");
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = guess_input;
      return true;
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: it still has the same outcome though

Comment: Sorry, I missed the change to get rid of `guess_input_text` and use just `guess_input` as you do not need to do parseInt on the text string in order to compare it - please see my complete solution above to clear up the explanation